# How to add multiple criteria in Matlab code to extract information

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab software and trying to read data from dataset with a specific criteria. My criteria work for the first line but not for the second line. Could you help how to modify the criteria in the second line.

First line criteria: select = 'Tanker oil'

Second line criteria: select = ['Tanker oil' , 'Passenger']

Regards

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data and the code you've used to extract the information?

Comment: It is a code which calculates the normal distribution from a dataset. Dataset contains lateral distribution of ships on a particular line. I just want to know how to add more than one ship types in criteria to get desired input. Should I put semicolon in between, AND sign or something else.
Do you still need the code, which is little big and some text refering to clomun name may not make sence to you.

Comment: without example code and sample data no one can help you reliably as we'd just be guessing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried to put the code in the comment section but it is longer than the allowed text in the comment section. Now I have split the data so that I won't use these restriction. 
Anyway thanks for your help :-).

Comment: Please don't put your code in comments. Please read how to create a [mre] and then [edit] your post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example with data from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html#btw1wrc-3

```
LastName = {'Sanchez';'Johnson';'Li';'Diaz';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Smoker = logical([1;0;1;0;1]);
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124 93; 109 77; 125 83; 117 75; 122 80];

smokers_over_40 = T(and(T.Smoker,T.Age>40),:);
```

If I want to filter the data using the criteria Smoker=true and Age > 40, I use `and(T.Smoker,T.Age>40)` which will create a logical array where only the rows which meet this criteria are true. I then use that logical array to select those rows from the table `T` to create the table `smokers_over_40`.

Without any further information from you about your data, this will hopefully give you some help with your question.

Your solution might look something like

```
tankers_and_passenger = Ships(or(Ships.type=='Tanker oil',Ships.type=='Passenger'));
```

Which would return a table that only contains ships that are either a tanker or passenger.

The `findgroups` function may also help you achieve this depending on your data (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html?s_tid=doc_ta)